# Appending string after every occurrence of other multiple substrings

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following string stored in a variable, say `txt1`:

`<a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscs" href="javascript:void(0)">1. fcfs.cs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscs" class="fa fa-star"></i><br><a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscpp" href="javascript:void(0)">2. fcfs.cpp</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscpp" class="fa fa-star"></i><br><a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfspy" href="javascript:void(0)">3. fcfs.py</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfspy" class="fa fa-star"></i><br><a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfsrs" href="javascript:void(0)">4. fcfs.rs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfsrs" class="fa fa-star"></i><br><a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstserveFCFSjava" href="javascript:void(0)">5. FCFS.java</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstserveFCFSjava" class="fa fa-star"></i><br>`

Now I want to insert `style='color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold'` after every `a target="_blank` present in the string.

How can I do so using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Why use Javascript to modify the HTML string if you could easily use CSS to style the coresponding elements:

```css
a[target="_blank"] + * {
  color: /* rgb(255, 255, 255) */
  red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscs" href="javascript:void(0)">
   1. fcfs.cs
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscs" class="fa fa-star"></i>
<br>
<a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscpp" href="javascript:void(0)">
  2. fcfs.cpp
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfscpp" class="fa fa-star"></i>
<br>
<a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfspy" href="javascript:void(0)">
  3. fcfs.py
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfspy" class="fa fa-star"></i>
<br>
<a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfsrs" href="javascript:void(0)">
  4. fcfs.rs
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstservefcfsrs" class="fa fa-star"></i>
<br>
<a target="_blank" id="myIdoperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstserveFCFSjava" href="javascript:void(0)">
  5. FCFS.java
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<i id="myStaroperatingsystemsrcfirstcomefirstserveFCFSjava" class="fa fa-star"></i><br>
```

Comment: Actually, these are a part of a complex code, and these elements are being generated dynamically. There's no option but to edit this string.

Comment: The example using CSS styles to modify the elements was a bit of a hint that you could just append a `<style>` tag to your string.

Answer (score 0):

If I absolutely had to do it this way, I'd use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). But I would try really hard to find a CSS-based solution first.

```
const substring = 'a target="_blank"'
const replacement = '$& style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold"'

txt1.replace(substring, replacement)
```